# Rank any number in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m looking for a function that will equal the [RANK function in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/RANK-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723).

> Returns the rank of a number in a list of numbers. The rank of a
>   number is its size relative to other values in a list. (If you were to
>   sort the list, the rank of the number would be its position.)

That is, take an array of (say 15) numbers, some of which might be identical, examine any number in the array and establish which rank in the array it holds. The highest number in the array is allocated a rank of 1 and identical numbers should hold the same ranking. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Some of us may not know Excel functions. Please share the same inputs and their respective outputs as well.

Comment: The Rank function appears to be deprecated in Excel *IMPORTANT: This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their usage. Although this function is still available for backward compatibility, you should consider using the new functions from now on, because this function may not be available in future versions of Excel* seems a bit odd to be replicating a broken function.

Comment: @Liam: The deprecation notice seems like a generic wording used for several deprecated functions. There is nothing broken about Excel's `RANK`. It is being replaced with `RANK.AVG` and `RANK.EQ` which only differ in how identical entries are ranked, and that behaviour has been explicitly specified by OP. `RANK.EQ` exactly matches the deprecated function `RANK`.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a variable which will be incremented only if the value and the previous value us unequal. This works only for sorted arrays.

```js
var data = [10, 8, 7, 7, 3, 3, 2, 1],
    rank = data.map(function (rank) {
        return function (a, i, aa) {
            return [a, aa[i - 1] === a ? rank : ++rank];
        };
    }(0));
    
console.log(rank.map(JSON.stringify));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Better mimic of `RANK`

```js
var data = [10, 8, 7, 7, 3, 3, 2, 1],
    rank = data.map(function (rank) {
        return function (a, i, aa) {
            return [a, aa[i - 1] === a ? rank : rank = i + 1];
        };
    }(0));
    
console.log(rank.map(JSON.stringify));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If you want to match the behavior of `RANK`, the entry `3` in your example should have the rank 5, not 4, as there are two entries ranked 3.

Comment: @DavidHedlund, so the rank is not continuous? like example 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Example 2 better mimics Excel's `RANK`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an assignment question but nevertheless i will try to answer: 
to be able to rank the numbers you may need to sort them out first thing, you can do so using library called lodash which has a function called sortby() or use any sorting algorithm(e.g. merge sort, insertion sort or bubble sort), once the elements are sorted you can just iterate over it, begining from the highest and keep pushing the values into a javascript object.

```
 (sortedArray)=>{
    var mySortedArrWithRank;
    for(int i=0;i<sortedArray.length;i++){
       if(sortedArray[i]!=sortedArray[i-1]){
           rank--;
       }   
       mySortedArrWithRank[rank].push(sortedArray[i]);
      }
    }
```

Moreover javascript arrays are associative in nature so its like key value all the time even though its a plain integer array.(Keep in mind)

Answer (score 0):

```
function rank(num, arr) {
   return arr
      .sort(function(a,b) { return b-a; })
      .indexOf(num) + 1;
}
```

The above function should replicate the behaviour of Excel's `=RANK`. You pass a value and an array, and the output is the rank of that value within the array:

```
rank(2, [1,2,7,12,3,2,4,12,30,5,6]); // > 9
```

If there are, as in the example above, two items with the rank 2, the next item will be ranked 4.