# Ranking numbers in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given an array of unique numbers, return a new array of rankings of the original array. For example, if your input array is `[10, 5, 20]`, the output should be `[2, 3, 1]`, since `10` is the second-largest number, `5` is the third largest, and `20` is the largest.

My answer is returning `[1,2,0]` rather than `[2,3,1]`. I can't figure where I'm going wrong?

```js
function rankings(arr) {
  // add whatever parameters you deem necessary 
  var sorted = arr.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  })
  var ranks = arr.slice().map(function(v) {
    return sorted.indexOf(v)
  });
  return ranks;
}

console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20]));
```

Comment: It is because the index starts at 0, not at 1. I think if you just add + 1 to the `return sorted.indexOf(v)` you are good to go.

Comment: your function is correct, its just that in javascript arrays are zero based, i.e. the first item has an index of 0. simply add +1 to each item in your ranks array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

- store the value along with the index in an array,
- sort by value,
- map the rank to the given value and index,
- sort by index to get the original sorting of the array,
- take the ranking.

```js
function rankings(array) {
    return array
      .map((v, i) => [v, i])
      .sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0])
      .map((a, i) => [...a, i + 1])
      .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
      .map(a => a[2]);
}

console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20])); // 2 3 1
```

Comment: how would you adapt this function to return equal rankings for equal values? so the array [10,15,5,5,5,1,9] returns [2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 3] and not [2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3] thank you

Comment: Ah I see you answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560779/16465606 I will try to merge the two answers

Comment: I changed the second `.map` line to `.map(function (rank) {return (a, i, arr) => [...a, (i>0) && arr[i-1][0] === a[0] ? rank : rank = i + 1]}(0))` and it worked

Comment: @TopMarx, great, you found it. i was on vacation.

Answer (score 3):

Gets much easier in ES6:

```js
function rankings(arr) {
  const sorted = [...arr].sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return arr.map((x) => sorted.indexOf(x) + 1);
};

console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20]));
```

One more way to consider multiple duplicate entries.

```js
function rankDuplicate(arr) {
  const sorted = [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => b - a);
  const rank = new Map(sorted.map((x, i) => [x, i + 1]));
  return arr.map((x) => rank.get(x));
}

console.log(rankDuplicate([10, 10, 5, 20]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
function rankings(arr){
  // add whatever parameters you deem necessary....good luck! 
  var sorted = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
  var ranks = arr.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v) + 1});
  return ranks;
}

rankings([10, 5, 20]); // [2, 3, 1]
```

I just add 1 to the index which starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

> Array index starts from `zero`.

You can add the index with one

```
sorted.indexOf(v) + 1
```

```js
function rankings(arr){
  // add whatever parameters you deem necessary....good luck! 
  var sorted = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
  var ranks = arr.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v) + 1 });
  return ranks;
}

console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because arrays have index '0' as first element. 
change your code to this:
`var ranks = arr.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v)+1});`